# Change Div direction in local Resources .resx

Tags: asp.net

How can I change direction of div in local Resources

I wrote in asp

```
<div id="maincontent" meta:resourcekey="maincontent"   >
</div>
```

and in local resource

```
Name:maincontent.dir 
value:rtl
```

but nothing is change

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is WebForms, you need to use `<% %>` to break-out of the render literal to insert code that injects content.

Assuming by "local resources" you're referring to `Resources.resx`, do this:

```
<div id="maincontent" dir="<%= Resources.maincontent_dir %>">
```

...assuming that you're using the IDE-generated `Resources` class and the generated property is called `maincontent_dir`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have error
i have 2 App_localresources
visitor.aspx.en.resx
visitor.aspx.ar.resx
and i have webform visitor.aspx 
I wrote as you told me dir="<%$ Resources.maincontent_dir %>" but is not work

Answer (score 0):

i use second part of resource name to point to a property, i also noticed that these information should get processed on server, mean you need to define run at server configuration:

here's what i needeed:

```
<body meta:resourcekey="body" runat="server">
```

The result will be:

```
<body style="direction: ltr" cz-shortcut-listen="true">
```

for:

```
body.Style ->   direction: ltr
```